# How to pass SMSESSION value from Win Client to asmx web service for Authentication

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement the SSO authentication with our WPF application.
Following is scenario

1. We have our asmx web service hosted with our web application which is firewall protected.
2. To login our web application or to view our web service in browser from production server we need to login using sso id.
   I have to  implement the SSO authentication with our WPF application.
3. First I have to consume the 3rd party web service which return me valid SMSESSION in string format if user is authenticated.
4. Then I have to pass this SMSESSION to my web service which is behind the fire wall.
5. Now the problem which I am facing is that I am unable to pass the SMSESSION value to our web service for authentication.

When i Try this it throws an exception

```
The content type text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD><BODY onLoad="document.AUTOSUBMIT.submit();">This page is used to hold your data while you are being authorized for your request.<BR><BR>You will be forwarded to continue the authorization process. If this does not happen automatically, please click the Continue button below.<FORM NAME="AUTOSUBMIT" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ACTION="https://xxx.com/ssologinforms/SSO_Generic_RME.fcc?TYPE=33554432&REALMOID=06-49a328ee-0d11-103b-ad01-83323a2d304d&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=POST&SMAGENTNAME=-SM-ooM6KmTLLwbCHi%2ffOCEVUabjNhcgULT5joVqmn4M77Tf0PAu3BFcfbexTaiWfZ4N&TARGET=-SM-http%3a%2f%2fdev--srvspeq%2eog%2ege%2ecom%2fSRVSpeQWebService%2easmx"><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="SMPostPreserve" VALUE="+rB+TqoVGXah2Uij3lfKDdCf2jsgE2NAUoujo+dFiiJ7yzqgpQaVnxRangTzcB/faU6BOAAcSBFUMUA1RpOCnVRVjN1cFbL0KhVu3y6IySj4gJE6X797kXkzMNEZgozuEz96g6PgQ6e5+sjqZaaNGii+Cy26QaD16fqQTI5VGkLdnD0fhNvJjXXgSBLNZd77nZz0aaMmz4cGZwnAElk7POTF/NBKdxCXS1l0U/iqqozqfBz0aFqLMpsy'.
```

please help me out in doing this

I use following code to get the Valid SMSESSION

```
string userId = txtUsername.Text.Trim(); // User to be authenticate with site minder //xxxxxxxxx
string passwrod = txtPassward.Password.Trim(); //password of user to be authenticate with site minder //xxxxxxxx
string applicationID = "XXXXXX"; // Application id. To be authenticate with JBoss Server.//xxxxxxxx
string applicationPassword = "XXXXXXXXX";//applicationPassword to be authenticate with JBoss Sever.//xxxxxxxx

 NamespaceName.AuthenticationServiceClient proxy = new NamespaceName.AuthenticationServiceClient();

                AuthenticationServiceRequest request = new AuthenticationServiceRequest();
                UserAttributes ut = new UserAttributes();
                ut.userName = userId;
                ut.password = passwrod;
                request.userAttributes = ut;
                AuthenticationServiceResponse response = null;
                try
                {
                    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                    proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = applicationID;
                    proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = applicationPassword;

                    response = proxy.passwordAuthenticate(request);

                    if (response.result != null)
                    {
                        switch (response.result.ToString())
                        {
                            case "SUCCESS":
                                MessageBox.Show("Valid SMSESSION :" + response.smSession.ToString());
                                break;
                            case "ERROR":
                                MessageBox.Show("ERROR CODE :" + response.errCode.ToString() + "\n Error Message :" + response.errMsg.ToString());
                                break;
                            default: MessageBox.Show("Response is neither SUCCESS nor ERROR, its something different\nERROR CODE :" + response.errCode.ToString() + "\n " + response.errMsg.ToString());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
}
```

How to pass SMSESSION to asmx web service